# SSRS URL Parameters Issue

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameters

I have an issue on where i cannot get the parameters to pass through via url.

Below is the url to the report i want to pass a single ID parameter (@ID).

I have tried a few ways, first time in passing via URL.

Any help grateful.

http://rpt.Server.local/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f%5bQuality+Sales+Report%5d%2fCP+Quailty+Sales+Details+Report+Preview&ViewMode=Detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rpt.Server.local/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f%5bQuality+Sales+Report%5d%2fCP+Quailty+Sales+Details+Report+Preview&ViewMode=Detail

instead of above link try below

Go to http://rpt.Server.local/Reportserver
find your report in above link and pass "&ID=(value) at the end of the url
or

http://rpt.Server.local/Reportserver/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f%5bQuality+Sales+Report%5d%2fCP+Quailty+Sales+Details+Report+Preview&ID=(value)